# How to configure multi-select Segmented Control on MacOS with SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, picker

The macOS HIG suggests that segmented controls can be multi select:
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/selectors/segmented-controls/

But the SwiftUI SegmentedPickerStyle seems to have no knob to configure it as such.  Is this simply a case of not implemented yet in SwiftUI for macOS?

```
                Picker(selection: self.$pickerSelection, label: Text("")) {
                Text("One").tag(0)
                Text("Two").tag(1)
                Text("Three").tag(2)
                }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

I can't seem to find a definition for SelectionValue as referenced here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker/3271572-init

Can Selection value be an array here?

Comment: Not supported now by SwiftUI, use NSSegmentedControl/NSViewRepresentable

Answer (score -1):

with the guidance from Asperi, I found this on the web and was able to make it work.  Use the custom segmented control.

https://onmyway133.github.io/blog/How-to-make-segmented-control-in-SwiftUI-for-macOS/

Things to note is that it is thin on how to wire it up to your view, but adding an init with initial state, labels/images and a closure as parameters allows you to  configure it programmatically and set its initial values (if any) and where to call on update from the Coordinator.